# How to open an html page in chrome

Tags: android, android-activity, browser

How to open a html page which is available in my application assets folder ? i want to open a html page which is already available in my application .. i found some code to open chrome but not able to open my html page ,
 here is the code

```
 File f=new File("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    try
    {
        Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
        i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        i.setData(uri);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
     Log.e("chrome ","Not installed ");
    }
```

please give some suggestion. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with "android.intent.action.VIEW"

Comment: Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);

Comment: thanks captain ,but i want to open a html page from assets folder ?

Comment: Hmmm... try to use a WebView instead open a new app. Here a reference and a basic usage example http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Or do you really need to open it in an external app?

Comment: yes , i don't want to open it in my app , i want to open it in external app .is there any other way captain ?

Comment: First, this route is so local for your app, and Chrome cant read it, because of security restrictions. You need to copy your file in to a public folder first. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Then try with that new route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer thanks for your valuable help.
I copied the html file from assets folder to internal memory in public folder 
then from there i loaded the html .

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible because your browser can't get file from your application. Another case is when you can copy your html-file to sdcard. But I'm not sure that browser can read Url with type "file".
You can put your html page on server and then load in browser. I think this is the best way to resolve this problem.